# java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessClassInPackage.com.sun.javafx.css.parser")

Tags: java-8, javafx-8, font-awesome, java-web-start

I'm deploying Javafx 8 application with java web start. I get this error when i try to access any class from thedependency jar fontawesomefx-8.9.jar
If I do not use any of the fontawesomefx-8.9   classes in my code, the application works fine. what could be the possible reasons for this behavior ?

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessClassInPackage.com.sun.javafx.css.parser")
```

Comment: You probably need to [sign your webstart-deployed application](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/packaging.html#BABJGFBH).

Comment: My application jar and the dependencies are all signed. but istill see the error . Do we have to copy any keystore files to the webserver ?

Comment: No, you do not need to place keystore files on the server.  Usually, when code signing, the keystore contains your private key, which you only use once to sign the code when the code is packaged.  The certificate for signature validation is usually [embedded in the JNLP data for your application](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/packaging.htm#BABCJCHH).

Comment: Adding the following lines to the jnlp made it work . Not sure if its the ideal way of doing it .<security><all-permissions/></security>

Comment: Probably fine.  Normally the JNLP file is generated (by maven or ant tasks) rather than hand-edited, so often you don't need to manually edit the jnlp to add that info.  You probably don't need all permissions, but you do need some additional permissions, so in all reality if you ask for all permissions rather than just some additional permissions, most users aren't going to care.  Probably best if you post info on how you solved this as a [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following lines to the jnlp file fixed the issue for me

```
<security>
<all-permissions/>
</security>
```